# Algorithm to find a all valid matrix permutations

Tags: algorithms, matrices, matrix

I have an array of $N^2$ numbers like $ a = \{ a_1,a_2, ..., a_{N^2} \}$ where all $a_i < F$ where $F$ is a fixed number.

I am looking for all permutations where if I put values in $A$ in order (i.e. fill the matrix row by row) in a $N \times N$ matrix $A_{N \times N}$ where sum of all columns and all rows are equal to $F$.

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & ... & a_N\\ 
a_{N+1} & a_{N+2} & ...  & a_{2N}\\ 
... & ... & ... & ...\\ 
a_{N^2-N+1} & a_{N^2-N+2} & ...  & a_{N^2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

There is a straight forward algorithm to find all permutations of $a$ in $O(N^2!)$ and check if sum of all rows and columns are equal to $F$.

Comment: The variable `F` appears to be used in two different meaning, one as a fixed number and the other is the matrix. Also, does the array `a` on the first sentence 
 happen to be `A` on the next sentence? Does the sentence "sum of all columns and all rows are equal to F" mean "the sum of values in any column or row is equal to F"?

Comment: What is the actual question here? Are you looking for an algorithm with a lower worst-case asymptotic runtime? In general, if you are listing all permutations matching your criteria then the output could be as large as $(N^2)!$, for example if $a$ just consists of $F/N$ repeated $N^2$ times.

Comment: Also, are all of your $a_i$ nonnegative? I'm guessing they are from the fact that you specify $a_i < F$. This affects whether it is possible to apply certain branch-and-bound algorithms.

Comment: I can't understand the "I am looking for..." sentence.  It says "where if..." but I don't see a "then...".  Also I don't know what you mean by "where sum of all...".  Can you break that down into multiple sentences?  What do you mean by "all permutations"?  Permutations of what?  Do you want to enumerate/list all such permutations?  To count the number of them? Please [edit] the question to address the feedback.